# Inhouse web hosting tips

Tags: web-hosting

I am setting up my computer to be a web server.

Are there any tips that you would like to add about maintaining an in house web server with regards to speed, security and performance?

Tip #1 - Get a UPS for electrical hiccups that might happen.

Tip #2 - ? what do you got ?

Comment: Make sure you're router is on the UPS! We fell foul of that one during an outage - the servers were up but the internet went down ;)

Comment: It may seem trivial, but make sure your management station\monitor is on the UPS as well. You want to make sure you can access the web server in the event of a power outage in case you need to perform a graceful shut down, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get a good firewall and set up your dmz properly.